# Getting error on `string` param with typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am getting this error:

`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ barkingRoadProject: string[]; }'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ barkingRoadProject: string[]; }'.ts(7053) (parameter) slideName: string`

when i try to `return` an array. here is my function: i am passing `barkingRoadProject` as a parameter

```
const slides = {
    "barkingRoadProject": ['boomerang-site1.jpg', 'boomerang-site2.jpg', 'boomerang-site3.jpg']
}

export const SlideSupply = (slideName: string): string[] => {
    return slides[slideName];
}
```

No able to understand the issue here. any one help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that in order to provide type safety, TypeScript doesn't (by default) support using unknown strings with brackets notation to look up properties on objects, because that bypasses type checking.

You have a couple of options:

#### Narrow the parameter type

You can make the type of the parameter more narrow, only accepting something known to be a valid property of the object:

```typescript
const slides = {
    "barkingRoadProject": ['boomerang-site1.jpg', 'boomerang-site2.jpg', 'boomerang-site3.jpg']
}

export const SlideSupply = (slideName: keyof typeof slides): string[] => {
//                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    return slides[slideName];
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBA2BLAJgUwjAvDA3gKBkJgCIAjAQwCcBrRMAcwCURzkAFSkAK1WCmIBcMANoByUiBABbVJXIMAtBERRUARgB0XAA71RAGhjjJMuYuWqATFt0GjE6bPn0lK1AGYbegLp4Avnh4qAAe2iCUsKCQsADKSGgxAK7a2vAAnlgwABQIKKgAcuQyQtSoaSAAZjBQadqolXDx6ACUQtCUdPTC3lgAfLgERJSoUImUYI15EMK5aIUy3gDc-kA)

Note that you'll only be able to call `SlideSupply` with a string known at compile-time to be a valid name for a `slides` property. So `SlideSupply("barkingRoadProject")` will work, but `SlideSupply(someString)` won't work if `someString` is only know to be a string, not necessarily `"barkingRoadProject"`.

#### A type assertion function

You can reassure TypeScript that the string-typed variable only has valid known values via a type [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions). The function would look like this:

```typescript
function assertValidSlideName(slideName: string): asserts slideName is keyof typeof slides {
    switch (slideName) {
        case "barkingRoadProject":
        case "any-other-valid-name-here":
            break;
        default:
            throw new Error(`Invalid slide name "${slideName}"`);
}
```

Then `SlideSupply` is:

```typescript
export const SlideSupply = (slideName: string): string[] => {
    assertValidSlideName(slideName); // ***
    return slides[slideName];
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Or you can make `SlideSupply` only accept `keyof typeof slides` and use the type assertion function prior to calling it.

#### String index signature

Alternatively, you could allow using any string by giving `sliders` a string [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures):

```typescript
const slides: {[key: string]: string[]} = {
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    "barkingRoadProject": ['boomerang-site1.jpg', 'boomerang-site2.jpg', 'boomerang-site3.jpg']
}

export const SlideSupply = (slideName: string): string[] => {
    return slides[slideName];
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBA2BLAJgUwgLhgbwNoGtUBPLaAJ0TAHMBdUqC63GgXxgF4cAoGXmAIgBGAQzL5KVAEohhyAApkQAK1TAo-LLgDkgkCAC2qMsOoBaCIiioAjADolABypaANDB17DxsxasAmeydXd10DIxMqc0tUAGZA5xouFi4uVAAPBxAyWFBIWABlJDR8gFcHB3giDhgACgQUVAA5YUN6RioASjaJZg4APm4+GDJUKBKyMDgi9Fx6tGbDGgBuJKA)

Comment: **Very** belatedly I realize: There's no way this isn't covered by previous questions and answers. Marked the answer "community wiki" (rather than deleting, though I could see deleting as well).